# What will the data type in Java be, when Schema fields type is Component Link in Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

Can you please provide some examples for mapping of Component Link Schema fields in Java.

Comment: This is very open ended question. I would recommend try something and let us know what have you tried and what was the output? That way it will be easier to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Component Link fields can be mapped to different View Model property types:

- `String` - represents the resolved Page URL for the linked Component.
- `Link` - represents the resolved Page URL for the linked Component.
- A subclass of `AbstractEntityModel` - represents the linked Component itself
- A subclass of `MediaItem` - in case of a Multimedia Component; represents the linked Component's Binary content.

Answer (score 0):

As Rick mentions Component Links are flexible in how they are mapped.

You can use the code on Github as a reference guide

See [Teaser's](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/704312b3e3e47eb93270698b23d9dc1ea2d4c7a1/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/core/model/entity/Teaser.java) link, of type [Link](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/release/1.2/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/api/model/entity/Link.java).

It shows a simple example using Link that exposes url, text and alternate text